# Button to delete table entry

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

i would like a button to delete the table entry next to it. But I am coming up short. I seem to be typing something wrong here is my attempt:

```
<td><a href="delete-quote.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><button class="btn-danger-dark">Delete</button></a></td>
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I only get the ELSE error message

I have tried small changes but with no affect. Im pretty sure its something small that I am missing.

my delete-quote.php code:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
//Connect DB
// on success delete : redirect the page to original page
$dbname = "siyakhat_ibroker";
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "siyakhat_root", "*****", $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM prerequest WHERE id = $id"; 

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
mysqli_close($conn);
header('Location: manage-quotes.php'); 
exit;
} else {
echo "Error deleting record";
}
?>
```

UPDATE

my dbconnect.php

```
<?php

$mysql_hostname ="localhost";
$mysql_user ="siyakhat_root";
$mysql_password ="****";
$mysql_database ="siyakhat_ibroker";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");

?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You'll also want to steer away from using GET for deletion requests. Some browser plugins can pre-fetch links like this causing *unexpected results* like deleting your entire database.

Comment: Why is there a `<button>` _inside_ your `<a>`?

Comment: Try passing in ?id=* as the get param in your url query string.

Comment: @tadman how would i fix this sir?

Comment: @TarekAdam what do you mean sir?

Comment: @RedZ - sorry, it was a bad joke.  What I posted is the sql injection that would delete everything from your table once you get things working.

Comment: @RedZ That comment has a number of links to resources to answer that very question.

Comment: Ah thank you @tadman much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you tried creating a db connection?

dbCon.php

```
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','your_pass_here');
define('DB','siyakhat_ibroker');
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect to the DB');
```

then your delete-quote.php should looks like:

```
 include(dbCon.php);
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $action = $_GET['action'];
 $tableName = 'prerequest';
if($action=='delete'){
    //deleting row
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $tableName WHERE id='$id'";
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if($r){
        $status="success";
    //assuming this file is in your root folder
    header('Location: manage-quotes.php');
    }else{
        $status="error ".mysqli_error($con) . ": " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
    echo $status;

}mysqli_close($con);
```

then call it with: delete-quote.php?id=1&action=delete

I recommend you to use a dynamic usage like Ajax calls instead an static  in your button, by creating your onClick events using jQuery and remove  rows dynamically with ajax calls.

Hope it works.
Cheers

Comment: do you have sqli extension enabled? can you try <?php info(); ?> and check if you have it already enabled? please share your error log.

Comment: I've updated the script with mysqli_error to see the error

Comment: i think i may be doing the button wrong.     `<a href="delete-quote.php?id=1&action=delete>"><button class="btn-danger-dark">Delete</button></a>`

Comment: yes you have an unclosed > after delete .....please use this   <a href="delete-quote.php?id=1&action=delete"><button class="btn-danger-dark">Delete</button></a>

Comment: Thank you sir, please see above my dbconnection.php and see if that isnt causing an issue with your delete-quote.php

Comment: well checking it now... you forgot to do the following to your SQL syntax: instead id=$id you should do id = '$id'

Comment: where is that sir i cannot find it

Comment: // sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM prerequest WHERE id = $id";

Answer (score 1):

From delete-quote.php replace "$sql" as given:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM prerequest WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this solution

```
<?php

 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "siyakhat_root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "siyakhat_ibroker";


 $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';


 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "DELETE FROM prerequest WHERE id = $id";

   if ($conn->query($sql)) {
       mysqli_close($conn);
       header('Location: manage-quotes.php');
      exit;
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record";
    }
  ?>
```